# format of multiple select with GET

Tags: html, forms, select, post, get

Is there a way to GET values in HTML form with multiple select as comma separated values?

Consider the following example:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<select multiple name="choice">
    <option value="1" selected>A</option>
    <option value="2" selected>B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Submitting the above code will give me:

```
http://example.com/index.php?choice=1&choice=2
```

I would like it to be:

```
http://example.com/index.php?choice=1,2
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should use JavaScript. But why?

Comment: @Vohuman Because my store based on Wordpress+Woocommerce takes parameters for filtering products this way. The upper example doesn't work. It seemed easier to change this than to change the way Woocommerce handles filters. Can you please provide an example how to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form with POST, then make a string of it and automatically submit it again with GET:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["choice"])) {
    $post_choice = $_POST["choice"];
    $choice = $post_choice[0];
    if (count($post_choice) > 1) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($post_choice); $i++) {
            $choice .= "," . $post_choice[$i];
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form id="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="choice" value="<?php print ($choice); ?>">
    </form>

    <script>document.getElementById("form").submit();</script>
    <?php
}

print ("GET choice: " . $_GET["choice"]);
?>

<form method="post">
    <select multiple name="choice[]">
        <option value="1" selected>A</option>
        <option value="2" selected>B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```